# App Center: how to automatically run a script somewhere between git clone and npm install?

Tags: npm, npm-install, githooks, visual-studio-app-center

In order to try and make App Center work with my monorepo React Native app, I am trying to find a way to insert a few bash scripts between the automated `git clone` and `npm install` called by App Center.
Indeed, App Center automatically `git clone` the linked project and then automatically runs `npm install` as soon as the cloning is done.

There is no native `post-clone` hook, I haven't been able to make [that package](https://github.com/git-hook/post-clone) work (and I don't even know if it could work since the `git clone` command would be called from a blank environment) and npm script `preinstall` [doesn't seem to work as it should since npm 7](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2660).

Does anyone know of a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution by myself: App Center actually comes with built-in hooks that allows to do exactly what I wanted to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/

Just add a `appcenter-post-clone.sh` at the root of your React Native app (or at the same level than your `.xcodeproj` or your `build.gradle` and add any bash script in there. It will be run right after the `git clone` by App Center and before the automatic `npm install`.